# how to scroll webview in vscode using javascript

Tags: javascript, webview, visual-studio-code

I created a extension to rendered markdown.

I want sync scroll editor and webview, just like built-in markdown preview but i can't find a way to scroll webview, visual studio code API also have not method to do this.

So what I can do to sync scroll editor and webview.

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to scroll webview content the same as you can scroll a normal webpage. Just call [`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) or similar apis in a script inside the webview itself.

Comment: No it doesn't work.. editor container has a separate scrollbar from the window..